# JS: Extracting data from an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a complex query with 100s of fields and nested fields. What I want to do is, for each Index, extract the English and French text. As you can see in the array, there is no French text for some indexes. In that case I want to get the English text.
For me extracting the English text works fine because the text is already there, but incase of French, I get undefined errors. What would be the best way to implement this. Is Loadash needed for this or just pure JS methods?

Just to be clear, I have erros with extracting french because in some fields, french text is not available, I want to use the english value in that case.

Also It is recommend if I am able to get the English and French values by it's language field rather than the index. I have no idea how to do that.

Any suggestion, documentation is appreciated. Thank you!

example array:

```
[
 {
    id: "1",
    name: [
      {
        language: "en-US",
        text: "HOLIDAY"
      }
    ],
    order: 6,
    Groups: [
      {
        name: [
          {
            language: "en-US",
            text: "REGULAR"
          }
        ],
        code: "REGEARN"
      },
      {
        name: [
          {
            language: "en-US",
            text: "CHARGE"
          }
        ],
        code: "CHARGE"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

and here is the code sandbox that reproduces my error:
[CODE SAND BOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/javascript-forked-5073j)
https://codesandbox.io/s/javascript-forked-5073j

EDIT:

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
{
  key: key,
  englishtext: "Value Here",
  frenchtext: "Value Here"
}
```

below is a working code, but issue is it does not work when there is no french language or that field. I get undefined errors. So is it possible I can get the needed data from the language field?

```
x.map((y) => ({
    key: y.id,
    name: y.name[0].text,
    groupname: y.Groups ? x.Groups[0].name?.[0].text : 'N/A',
  }))
```

Comment: Please include the code in your stack overflow question that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Sure I'll do it in a while I'm away from my computer rn :)

Comment: How do you want the output to be? Do you want to pass an item id and get the english and french texts along with the code? Or do you just want a string array of all the english and french texts if they exist?

Comment: Given that we have no idea of what the output format you want is or the input format actually is, as your code example fails because it's an array of arrays the best I can say is to try a function like this. 
```
console.log(getLanguageTexts(x[1]), "en-US")

function getLanguageTexts(group, preferredLanauge) {
  const prefLangResults = group.name.filter(c => c.language === preferredLanauge)
  
  return prefLangResults.length > 0 ? prefLangResults : group.name.find(c => c.language === "en-US")
}```

Comment: I am getting this data from an API, I would like to populate it in a table. If the website language is English, I wanna fetch and display the English, Otherwise It will display French, Incase French text is unavailable, it must go back to English.

Comment: Give us an example of the output. Do you want the code, the group, the item ids, the text? I have a feeling that the text is meaningless without the proper context.

Comment: @RaySuelzer I wanna pass the item ID and get the english and french texts, that would be easy to implement for me in my application.

Comment: Please see the updated question, I have included more snippets. I apologize the details are very raw but I tried and could not implement this so I am asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you expect result like this? If you don't mind lodash.

```
const _ = require('lodash');

const getNames = (arr) => {
  return arr.map((obj) => {
    const id = obj.id;
    const englishtext = _.get(obj, 'name[0].text', 'N/A');
    const frenchtext = _.get(obj, 'name[1].text', englishtext);

    return { id, englishtext, frenchtext };
  });
};
        
console.log(getNames(x));
// [
//   { id: '1', englishtext: 'HOLIDAY', frenchtext: 'HOLIDAY' },
//   { id: '2', englishtext: 'Stat Holiday', frenchtext: 'Congé Férié' },
//   { id: '3', englishtext: 'Over', frenchtext: 'Over' }
// ]
```

Comment: this is good thank you! Lodash really helps in this situation.